# bash script for batch trimming of pdf files

Tags: bash, pdfcpu

I have multiple pdf files in a directory. I want to leverage a pdf library that saves certain pages in a new file, probably a separate output folder.

What's the best way to do it?

This is the code that I wrote but needs more addition.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Saves 1st 4 pages or every pdf file to a new file.

for i in *.pdf; do


pdfcpu trim -pages "1-4" ${i}.pdf output ${i + %}.pdf


done
```

This code doesn't run, but I have reached this level.
My question,

1. How to iterate over each file
2. Save it in a different folder with first 4 pages only.

The library I am using is [PDF CPU](https://github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu), specifically [its `trim` function](https://pdfcpu.io/core/trim).

Comment: Does your code not work?  The `${i + %}` syntax does not look correct. It's not actually clear what your question is.  What problem are you trying to solve? pdftk is an alternative tool for manipulating pdf files.

Comment: Added comments to the question

Comment: Where should the output files go? What name should they have? If you only had one file, what command would you run? Show us that so we can extrapolate to the others.

Comment: The output could go to /output.
A single file to edit is quite easy. 
pdfcpu trim -pages "1-4" test.pdf 4test.pdf

Comment: You're setting `$i` to the full name of each pdf file. `${i}.pdf` has teh extension repeated twice.

Answer (score 2):

You were close.

```
#! /bin/bash -

shopt -s nullglob

mkdir -p trimmed || exit

ret=0
for file in ./*.pdf; do
  pdfcpu trim -pages 1-4 "$file" "trimmed/$file" || ret="$?"
done
exit "$ret"
```

- When using globs, it's good practice to use a `./` prefix to avoid problems with filenames that start with `-`.
- in bash/sh, parameter expansions must be quoted.
- in bash/sh, if a glob doesn't match, the pattern is passed as-is to the command. In bash, you can work around that misfeature with `shopt -s nullglob` (or `failglob` with a different effect).
- `$i` in your loop contains the full file name including the `.pdf` extension. With `${i}.pdf`, you'll end up with two extensions, and `pdfcpu` won't be able to find the corresponding `file.pdf.pdf` file.
- `${i + %}` doesn't make any sense. It's not clear to me what you wanted to achieve with that. If you wanted the output file name for `$file` == `file.pdf` to be `trimmed/file%.pdf`, you'd pass `"trimmed/${file%.pdf}%.pdf"` as the output file path.
- according to [the manual](https://pdfcpu.io/core/trim), you're not meant to have `output` there.
- remember to pay attention to failures and  what to do when they occur. Here, if any of the `pdfcpu` command fails, we carry on with the rest, but we do report their failure in the script's exit status.